# Restrict nuget package updates to current versions for some packages

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

Is there a way to disable updates of specific nuget packages installed in a project?

I have made some local modifications to a couple of javascript library packages and do not want to run the risk of someone updating over the top of my changes in the future.

I've never created my own nuget package, I'm guessing one option might be to fork the existing packages?

Answer (score 45):

You could try [constraining the package](https://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/versioning#Constraining_Upgrades_To_Allowed_Versions) so it your project will only allow a particular version to be used. Then all updates to any newer version will be prevented.

You can do this by editing your project's package.config file. For example, the line below should only allow version 2.1.0 to be used.

```
<package id="SomePackage" version="2.1.0" allowedVersions="[2.1.0]" />
```

Comment: Looks promising, will give that a go. I guess I need to get an old version, apply your solution and test updating to prove it. Will be sure to come back and mark your response as the accepted answer if it works, thanks!

Comment: Did this approach actually work for you? I have tried the same to restrict updates, but they are still listed on the updates tab

Comment: @NAJ - What IDE are you using? Visual Studio 2015 seems to ignore the constraints when showing updates but the update should still fail.

Comment: Hi Matt, yes you are right, I was assuming it would not show up in the list, but when you try to update it does give the error and stops it. Thanks

Comment: This *does* hide the package if managing project level NuGet packages, whereas managing Solution level packages, the update shows but will not install. (VS2017 Community)

Comment: Is there a way of doing this using the NuGetPackage management via the CSProject file "PackageReference" rather than "Packages.config"?

Comment: You can use version wildcards in PackageReferences but right now it does not seem that Visual Studio, nor Visual Studio on Mac, restrict updates to those allowed versions.

Comment: @MattWard You can restrict it by putting the version e.g. 4.61.0 in brackets like so: [4.61.0]. You still will see updates when on the Installed tab, but you won' be adviced to update on Updates tab.

Comment: With VS2019 and the [new csproj format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj), adding `allowedVersions` to `PackageReference` in the csproj doesn't prevent the solution-level NuGet package manager from updating the package version.

Comment: So what is the solution for the latest csproj and VS19?

Comment: This still does not work for me in VS2019. According to the doc, something like `<PackageReference Include="Prism.Unity" Version="(,7.3" />` should exclusively restrict the version to up to 7.2.xxx in the csproj file, but it doesn't and it actually removes the nuget dependency from the project, ending in build error. Moving this reference to a packages.config removes it totally from the nuget tabs (even doesn't show up in installed tab), I guess dependencies should be either packages.config or csproj, but not mixed.

Comment: I also tried this, which didn't work either `<PackageReference Include="Prism.Unity" Version="7.2.*.*" />`

Comment: @SiavashMortazavi when you switch a project from package ref to package config, you have to close the VS instance then delete the `.vs` directory in the solution folder and then it should load correctly. THere is some metadata hiding in that folder that makes it think the project is still PR based.

Comment: It worked when I edited the packages.config file on VS2019. Thanks

Comment: You also have to use the correct syntax, e.g. `allowedVersions="(,7.3)"`. For `<PackageReference>`, there is no `allowedVersions` and the range is placed in the `Version` attribute.

Answer (score 29):

I don't have a package.config. (VS 2019, .NET Core 3.1) What I did instead was changing the .csproj of the project which had the package which I needed to stop showing up for updates.

In my case it was EPPlus, and I wrapped the version number within square brackets.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="EPPlus" Version="[4.5.3.3]" />
</ItemGroup>
```

After that, it stopped showing up on the Updates tab in Nuget Package Manager.

And it doesn't give any option to update from anywhere else too. (Installed tab, Nuget for the solution, etc)

You'll need to restart VS to get rid of the yellow triangles next to the packages.

Comment: That actually works. Does anyone know where this is documented?

Comment: @RockingChair see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#version-ranges

Answer (score 8):

**EDIT:**

**WARNING: Please note that this works only for "Manage Nuget packages for a [project]" (which is rarely used), not "Manage Nuget packages for Solution" (which is the one you use every other day). See comments.**

**So this is no solution at all. I will keep it here for some random googlers who will try this, but it is almost useless.**

For `PackageReference` you can block updates on single version like this:

```
<PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity">`
  <Version>[3.1.1]</Version>
</PackageReference>
```

For some reason, it has to be in its own element and not in an attribute, so you are stuck with editing your .csproj by hand.

VS2019 will look funny (some yellow triangles) but just restart it and it will take effect.

It is not the same as `allowedVersions=` because AFAIK you can lock to exactly one version only (for example, `[3.1.0, 3.1.1]` or `(3.0.0, 3.1.1]` or whatever else does NOT work!)

*(I know I am necromanting this question - the accepted answer is about the older tag `<Package />` - my answer is about newer the tag `<PackageReference />`).*

Comment: You had my hopes up thinking you found some magic, but this does not prevent the package from being upgraded and only hides it from the upgrade tab of the "Manage nuget packages for [project]".  I can still update it from the Install tab of that dialog. Also it still shows up on the "Manage nuget for Solution", which is generally the only view that should be getting used (except for rare occasions)

Comment: oh, frak, you are right - that's what I was afraid of. I found this in some discussion in github and it looks ok-ish (And I tested only "manage nuget for project", not for solution.

Comment: In VS2022 this also works for "Manage Nuget packages for Solution"