# How to prevent upgrade of references when using NuGet

Tags: .net, msbuild, nuget

I have a .csproj project with simple reference.

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="12.0">
...
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
  </ItemGroup>
...
```

I also have project.json for NuGet references:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "SomePackage": "1.1.1-beta",
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win": {}
  },
...
```

It used to work just fine with this setup.
But recently "SomePackage" started to depend on another package which, through bunch of transitive dependencies, depend on NETStandard.Library" version="1.6.1".

```
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration</id>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETStandard1.1">
        <dependency id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" version="1.1.0" />
        <dependency id="NETStandard.Library" version="1.6.1" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

NETStandard.Library depend on newer version of System.Net.Http 4.1.0.0

And when I compile the project, the assembly starts directly referencing new version System.Net.Http.

And then of course it start to demand this dll in runtime.

I compile against .Net 4.6.2 and Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration compiled against .Net standard 1.1. So it should work on the machine with 4.6.2 installed.
But 4.6.2 does not contain this new version of System.Net.Http 4.1.0.0.

So my question is how I can stop NuGet and MsBuild to upgrade direct references of my assembly to versions of transitive dependencies of packages I use?

Comment: I found out that this is due AutoUnify functionality in MsBuild. But it is very little information about AutoUnify. And it is not clear how to turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

If its only assembly references you are worried about, then `AutoUnifyAssemblyReferences` is your answer. If you are using Visual Studio 2017, go to the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin` (or the appropriate path where the corresponding MSBuild version is installed) and search for `Microsoft.CSharp.targets` file. This is the targets file used by Visual Studio and hence by MSBuild while building your solution. Within this file, you can add the following tag:

```
   <AutoUnifyAssemblyReferences>false</AutoUnifyAssemblyReferences>
```

Save the file after these changes. All subsequent builds will prevent auto-assembly version upgrades.
**WARNING**: This setting will apply to all projects that you build using that particular version of Visual Studio / MSBuild. Once your problem is resolved, you can revert back to the original version of the targets file.

For preventing NuGet auto-upgrades, you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563518/restrict-nuget-package-updates-to-current-versions-for-some-packages) stack-overflow post that addresses this issue.

EDIT: If you want to control this at the Project level, here is how you can do it. In your `csproj` file, identify the section with `<Target>` tag (it might be commented), and modify it as below:

```
   <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" >
      <Target Name="BeforeResolveReference">
        <AutoUnifyAssemblyReferences>false</AutoUnifyAssemblyReferences>
      </Target>
   </Import>
```

I have never tried it myself, but this should work in theory. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366724.aspx) is a link of all the target names that you can override to set the `AutoUnifyAssemblyReferences` flag to false.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Too bed this can not be controlled on project level. Modifying files on build machine will interfere with other builds and it is pretty much show stopper for VSTS agents.

Comment: It can also be controlled at project level, but have never tried it myself. Updated the answer with steps to accomplish this.

Comment: The Project level solution given has syntax errors. I think the XML should be: `<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" /> <Target Name="BeforeResolveReference"> <PropertyGroup> <AutoUnifyAssemblyReferences>false</AutoUnifyAssemblyReferences> </PropertyGroup> </Target>`

Comment: There's definitely an error in the original per-project XML snippet given, because the Import tag shown is self-closing but then there's an Import close tag too.  If I stop the Import tag from self-closing I get an error that the Target tag cannot nest within the Import tag.  I followed vyrp's code snippet and that lets me load the project file in Visual Studio (so Target is a peer tag of the Import tag, not a child tag), but I still get the same warning MSB3277 messages after log messages from "Unified Dependency" processing saying it is changing the dependency to Unsafe v5.0.0.0.