# Issues working on projects targeting .NET Framework 4.5 and 4.6.2 both versions in same repository

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, nuget, .net-4.5, nuget-package-restore

Recently we upgraded our .NET solution from .NET Framework 4.5 to 4.6.2. The project is in Git repository and we are having multiple branches of this repository. We re-targeted the Nuget packages to 4.6.2 and with that I could see Nuget packages getting restored automatically while rebuilding the solution which is absolutely fine and expected. Now, most of the packages are having a folder named as "net462" which contains a DLL for the package targeting to .NET Framework 4.6.2. However, folder "net45" is empty now.

The problem is that when a developer switches to an old branch which points to .NET Framework 4.5, s/he gets number of errors related to reference not found. I assume because there exists a folder for "net45" but there is no assembly in that.

Could anyone please suggest how can I make both the branches (targeting to 4.5, and 4.6.2) building successfully on a same machine with correct Nuget dependencies?

Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It is not obvious why the net45 subdirectory is empty, not standard behavior.  Were they stripped by hand and checked into source control perhaps?  Nuget restore doesn't fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could anyone please suggest how can I make both the branches (targeting to 4.5, and 4.6.2) building successfully on a same machine with correct Nuget dependencies?

Agree with the comment of Hans "*It is not obvious why the net45 subdirectory is empty, not standard behavior. Were they stripped by hand and checked into source control perhaps?*". Nuget would not delete `.dll` file in the .NET 4.5 folder.

When you switch to an old branch which points to .NET Framework 4.5, the path of assembly in the Properties winodw should point to the `...\lib\net45\..` folder. And the default behavior of Git is not add the packages folder in to the source control. So, then you build your project from old branch, Visual Studio will restore nuget packages automatically. After restore complete, Visual Studio could find the assembly in the folder "net45".

So, to resolve this issue, first, you should make sure **the nuget packages in the nuget repository contains the assembly in folder for "net45"**, then when you switches to an old branch, check if there is a `\packages` folder in the solution folder, if yes, remove it and check if there is nuget restore behavior when you build the project on an old branch(Check the log on the output window).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the branches targeting .NET 4.5 are grabbing the latest version of the NuGet packages rather than restricting themselves to the versions of the NuGet packages supporting .NET 4.5. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563518/restrict-nuget-package-updates-to-current-versions-for-some-packages#answer-22563668) for an example of how to do that ([the Microsoft documentation on NuGet versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/package-versioning#version-ranges-and-wildcards) contains additional details about restricting version ranges).

Ideally your change of NuGet packages to .NET 4.6.2 at least is a new major version of the NuGet packages, but restricting the version works as long as they are a different version.

Comment: Actually this is not about NuGet packages versions, but its for "targetFramework" version. We have same nuget package versions across all branches, but targetFramework is "net462" in one branch, whereas "net451" in rest of the branches.