# How to prevent Visual Studio's Nuget Consolidate from operating on a particular project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, nuget

How do I prevent Visual Studio's Nuget Consolidate from operating on a particular project?

This is the opposite of [How to enforce same nuget package version across multiple c# projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26792624/how-to-enforce-same-nuget-package-version-across-multiple-c-sharp-projects).

We have a DLL that gets built with the project that has the responsibility of down-migrating the data store to any previous version. It is important to understand, this DLL will *never* be loaded by the current version, but always by an older version. As such it has references to ancient versions of everything.

Recently, Visual Studio added this nice [Nuget Consolidate](http://ericphan.net/blog/2016/1/22/consolidating-nuget-package-versions) feature to upgrade everything at once. This is normally a great feature and I'd use it all the time, but this one DLL really really needs to be exempt.

I can definitely add tests to the build that go check its references and fail the build if they are wrong, but I'd rather prevent the mistake from being made in the first place. Yeah we got documentation that says don't do that. There's no chance of the developer remembering the document he read a year ago.

Comment: Does the `allowedVersions` attribute work for you, [as per this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22563518/634824)?

Comment: @MattJohnson: I'm short on docs. That would work if the result doesn't get written into the assembly as dynamic resolved version is likely to be higher than the reference version.

Comment: @MattJohnson: Verified works with ildasm. Looks like a dupe to me with good Google matching now.