# How to Lock a Package Version from Nuget Updates

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget

I am using `Aspose` to do some doc management and our license only gives us a year of updates, which now has expired. So when, in typical fashion, we update our packages and get the latest version of `Aspose` it breaks our app. Is there a way to lock down those packages from showing up in the `Nuget Package Updates` list, or at least to prevent changes to the versions via the the `Nuget Update` process? I looked at various `Nuget` and `Microsoft` references and didn't see anything, but am hoping someone here knows some secret sauce?

[image: Nuget Package Manager]

Comment: Why not just...not update them? Perhaps add a test that fails if the version numbers don't match, and prevent pull request from being merged if that's the case?

Comment: We have a team of 10+ devs and it's one more thing to remember...

Comment: Then why not do as I suggested and add a test for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two ways I can think to do this:

- Create a new Nuget package that you dont rev that contains the references you want to lock. that way they would just never show up in the update list.
- Create a test like @mason suggested. I would start with code that finds the assembly with the name you want to lock then you can check its version. you can either write it as an exact match (easist) or not to exceed a specific version (more work but you could use an earlier version)

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old but there is an attribute you can add in the packages.config file that locks the version as Matt Ward answered here:

[Restrict nuget package updates to current versions for some packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563518/restrict-nuget-package-updates-to-current-versions-for-some-packages)

For us it was the UmbracoCms package that had breaking changes in the next version.

```
<package id="UmbracoCms" version="7.15.5" allowedVersions="[7.15.5]" targetFramework="net472" />
```

You can find more information about version restrictions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to just stop using NuGet for it and reference the DLLs manually.

1. Look in the `bin` folder (where your compiled project is) and copy any `Aspose.*` files to a new folder in your project directory.
2. Uninstall the Aspose NuGet packages.
3. In Visual Studio Solution Explorer, right-click 'References' -> 'Add Reference' -> 'Browse' -> 'Browse' and pick the DLLs from the folder you created in step 1.

Answer (score 1):

With the latest `PackageReference` format simply add square brackets around the version number in `.csproj` file:

```
<PackageReference Include="MYPACKAGE" Version="[2.6.0]" />
```

This will freeze the dependency version and it won't show up in updates.

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning?tabs=semver20sort#version-ranges

P.S. This is an old question but it still shows up as the #1 Google result for me, so I added another answer.