# Is there a way to make a NuGet package non-updatable?

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2019

Like the title says, we discovered that due to some older code lying around in our code base, we can no longer update `System.IdentityModel` to a newer version. Is it possible to put *something/anything* in NuGet Package Manager or in `packages.config` that can mark it as a package that shouldn't or can't be updated any longer?

It will just help avoid anyone else trying the same exercise again and coming to the same fruitless results.

Comment: How about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22563668/7225096

Comment: Thanks @Peska, that does indeed seem to do the trick. Would this question be considered a duplicate of that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to put something/anything in NuGet Package Manager or
>   in packages.config that can mark it as a package that shouldn't or
>   can't be updated any longer?

**First**, thanks to **Peska** for sharing the useful info.

In `packages.config` file, you can use `allowedVersions` node to limit nuget package updates just like this:

```
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="12.0.3" targetFramework="net472" allowedVersions="[12.0.3]" />
```

With it, you cannot update the current version of this nuget package.

More info you can refer to [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#version-ranges).