# How to hide a package in Visual Studio package manager

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I have run out of support for the Devexpress license and now one package (DevExtreme.Aspnet.Mvc) shows in my package update in Visual Studio, everytime I do a "Manage Nuget packages for Solution...".

Since I won't be getting any updates for this, will I be able to somehow hide this from view?

[image]

Comment: Add square brackets around version number like: <PackageReference Include="DevExtreme.AspNet.Mvc" Version="[19.1.12]" />

Comment: @Peska, thanks for the reply. I tried it in the package.config and I get error. Then I tried it in the .csproj file and still appears. So I don't believe that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66688310/14324452), you could follow these steps:

1. Remove `DevExtreme.Aspnet.Mvc` from the package.config file
2. Edit csproj file
3. Use `PackageReference` to add this package into your project

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DevExtreme.Aspnet.Mvc">
      <Version>[19.1.12]</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

The note: this workaround just works for project instead of solution. So you need to apply it into each project.

Comment: Dylan thank you for your reply. It seems to have worked. Before I mark as solution I just wanted to clarify something. When editing the csproj, there is a reference to the package in the form <Reference Include="DevExtreme.AspNet.Mvc.....Do I remove that or shall I leave it?

Comment: Yes, you also need to remove it.